# algorithm of the 'No-three-in-line problem'?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Are there some kind of mature [No-three-in-line problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-three-in-line_problem) algorithm in popular languages ( such as Java, C#, Ruby, JavaScript etc) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not direct answer, but if you like to draw complete graph (I don't know your application), you might be interested in checkout out [graphviz programming library](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php), or their [theory references](http://www.graphviz.org/Theory.php).